# Como enviar um e-mail através de um script BAT?

Tags: windows, script, email, envio-de-email, bat

Tenho esse script que consegui aqui mesmo e ele verifica o status de um programa e toda vez que identificar que ele está fechado, o reabre.

```
@echo off

::Coloque aqui o caminho para o programa:
set Programa=C:\Windows\notepad.exe

For %%a in ("%Programa%") do set "Processo=%%~nxa"

:Loop
cls
echo.
echo  Procurando:  %Processo%
tasklist |find /i "%Processo%" 1>nul 2>nul
if not %Errorlevel% EQU 0 start "" "%Programa%"
timeout /t 10 >nul
goto :Loop
```

Porém, preciso que seja disparado um e-mail informando toda vez que o script abre o programa.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Teria que usar ou powershell ou um programa de terçeiros dentro do bat para fazer a parte de envio de e-mail.

Comment: A operação de enviar um email tem que ser realizada com o powershell em modo administrativo pois é necessário habilitar o TSL na seção para proteger a comunicação de ataques MITM.  Quanto aos MUA citados na resposta o sendmail versão Windows não deve ser utilizado com outro protocolo que não seja SMTP pois os outros protocolos nessa versão não suportam criptografia, o Send-MailMessage não deve ser utilizado pois foi [descontinuado por não suportar criptografia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.2#description)

Comment: deve ser utilizado em seu lugar o [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) e o Outlook pode ser utilizado com segurança desde que o TLS esteja habilitado na sessão powershell. Então aqui são duas perguntas *Como Habilitar TLS 1.2 numa sessão PowerShell* e *como enviar um email seguro do PowerShell*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode tentar usando:

- Programa de terceiros, como o [sendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/#download)
- Usando [bat](/questions/tagged/bat) + [ps1](/questions/tagged/ps1) // hibrido em um único bat
- Usando o PowerShell (tem muitos [exemplos publicados online](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+send+email+by+command+line&rlz=1C5CHFA_enBR972BR972&ei=hURxYqqCB-vz1sQPzqew8Ak&ved=0ahUKEwjq2KCezcP3AhXruZUCHc4TDJ4Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=powershell+send+email+by+command+line+in+pt-BR&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABOgcIABBHELADOgYIABAWEB5KBAhBGABKBAhGGABQrgpYwixgly9oAXABeACAAaABiAG_CZIBAzAuOZgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz))

---

- Usando o [sendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/#download)

```bat
@echo off 

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd/d "%~dp0" & set "_prog=C:\Windows\notepad.exe"

:loop
cls & echo\
for %%a in ("!_prog!")do set /p "'=Procurando: %%~nxa..." <nul & 2>nul (
    tasklist /fo list | 1>nul find /i "%%~nxa" || call :mail "%_prog%"
    timeout 010 1>nul & goto :loop )

:mail
start "" /b /d "%~dp1" "%~nx1"
.\sendEmail.exe -f "Nome Remetente <e_mail_do@remetente.com>" -t "Nome Destinatario <e_mail_do@destinatario.com>" -cc "copia_cc <e_mail_de@copiacarbono.com>" -o message-file=.\"arquivo_conteudo_mensagem.html" -v -l .\"seu_arquivo.log" -u "texto de assunto" -a ".\arquivo para anexo 1.docx" -a ".\arquivo para anexo 2.xlsx" -s imap.do_seu_servidor.com:porta -xu e_mail_do@remetente.com -xp senha_remetente 1>nul 2>&1
exit /b
```

---

**obs.: 1** Como o comando/executável do `sendEmail` tem uma linha muito comprida, você também pode usar escapes (`ˆ`) para cada quebra de  linha, mas observe de terminar cada linha quebrada com o `ˆ`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```bat
.\sendEmail.exe -f "Nome Remetente <e_mail_do@remetente.com>" ^
                -t "Nome Destinatario <e_mail_do@destinatario.com>" ^
               -cc "copia_cc <e_mail_de@copiacarbono.com>" ^
                -o message-file=.\"arquivo_conteudo_mensagem.html" ^
                -v -l .\"seu_arquivo.log" -u "texto de assunto" ^
                -a ".\arquivo para anexo 1.docx" -a ".\arquivo para anexo 2.xlsx" ^
                -s imap.do_seu_servidor.com -xu e_mail_do@remetente.com -xp senha_remetente 1>nul 2>&1
exit /b
```

---

**obs.: 2** Para fazer uso de um smtp "externo" para disparo de seus e-mail, é bem provável que algumas configurações deverão ser aplicadas na sua conta e considerar as observações pertinentes dessas ações.  *Para fins de exemplo "linkei" aqui os do **[GMail.com](https://sistemaaula.com.br/crm/knowledge-base/article/como-utilizar-o-servidor-smtp-do-google-para-enviar-e-mails)***

---

- Portando seu script para modo hibrido [[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)/[bat](/questions/tagged/bat) + [ps1](/questions/tagged/ps1)]

```bat
<# :
@echo off

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd/d "%~dp0" & set "_prog=C:\Windows\notepad.exe"

:loop
echo\
for %%a in ("!_prog!")do set /p "'=Procurando: %%~nxa..." <nul & 2>nul (
    tasklist /fo list | 1>nul find /i "%%~nxa" || call :mail "%_prog%"
    timeout 010 1>nul & goto :loop )

:mail
start "" /b /d "%~dp1" "%~nx1"
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "$input | &{[ScriptBlock]::Create((Get-Content \"%~f0\") -join [char]10).Invoke(@(&{$args}))}"
exit /b 

#>

write-host 'PowerShell enviando E-mail'
$to = "Nome Destinatario <e_mail_do@destinatario.com>"
$cc = "copia_cc <e_mail_de@copiacarbono.com>"
$subject = "seu assunto de e-mail"
$body = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot + 'arquivo_texto_mensagem.txt' | Out-String

$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application

$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.To = $to
$mail.Cc = $cc
$mail.Subject = $subject
$mail.HTMLBody = $body
$mail.Body = $body

$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Display()
```

- Ou...

```bat
<# :
@echo off

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd/d "%~dp0" & set "_prog=C:\Windows\notepad.exe"

:loop
echo\
for %%a in ("!_prog!")do set /p "'=Procurando: %%~nxa..." <nul & 2>nul (
    tasklist /fo list | 1>nul find /i "%%~nxa" || call :mail "%_prog%"
    timeout 010 1>nul & goto :loop )

:mail
start "" /b /d "%~dp1" "%~nx1"
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "$input | &{[ScriptBlock]::Create((Get-Content \"%~f0\") -join [char]10).Invoke(@(&{$args}))}"
exit /b 

#>

write-host 'PowerShell enviando E-mail'

$de         = "Nome Remetente <e_mail_do@remetente.com>"
$para       = "Nome Destinatario <e_mail_do@destinatario.com>"
$cc         = "copia_cc <e_mail_de@copicarbono.com>" 
$anexo      = ".\arquivo para anexo 1.docx",".\arquivo para anexo 2.xlsx"
$assunto    = "texto de assunto"
$corpo      = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot + 'arquivo_texto_mensagem.txt' | Out-String
$BodyAsHtml  = $true
$SMTPServer = "smtp.do_seu_servidor.com"
$SMTPPorta  = "numero_da_porta"

Send-MailMessage -From $de -to $para -Cc $Cc -Subject $assunto -Body $corpo -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port $SMTPPorta -UseSsl -Credential (Get-Credential) -Attachments $anexo
```

Comment: @lo-ol É você ItWAsnMe?

Comment: @RicardoBohner o código afirma que sim e vc já viu!